# Property 'do' does not exist on type 'void'

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I am trying to retrieve data from Firebase within a service and use it in a component in order to display the data on my template. I'm using Angularfire2 & Firebase.

Service code:

```
export class MaterialDataFirebaseService {

  constructor(private db:AngularFireDatabase) {

  }

  getData(group, endKey?) {
    let query = {
      orderByKey: true,
      limitToFirst: group
    };

    if(endKey) query['startAt'] = endKey;

    // tried the two commented blocks below, but gave errors

    // return this.db.list('/', {
    //   query
    // });

    // return this.db.list('/', ref => {
    //   let q = ref.limitTolast(25).orderByKey(true);
    //   return q;
    // });

    this.db.list('/', ref => 
    ref.orderByKey().limitToFirst(group))
    .valueChanges()
    .subscribe(materialData => {
      return materialData;
    });
  }
}
```

Component code:

```
export class LibraryMaterialCardComponent implements OnInit {
  materials: Material[];
  firebaseData = new BehaviorSubject([]);

  group = 8;
  endKey = '';
  finished = false;

  constructor(private dataService:DataService, private _materialDataFirebaseService: MaterialDataFirebaseService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.getMaterialData().subscribe((materials) => {
      this.materials = materials;
    });

   this.getFirebaseData();
  }

  onScroll() {
    this.getFirebaseData();
  }

  private getFirebaseData(key?) {
    if(this.finished) return;

    this._materialDataFirebaseService.getData(this.group + 1, this.endKey)
      .do(firebaseData => {
        this.endKey = _.last(firebaseData)['$key']
        const newData = _.slice(firebaseData, 0, this.group)
        const currentData = this.firebaseData.getValue;

        if(this.endKey == _.last(newData)['$key']) {
          this.finished = true;
        }

        this.firebaseData.next(_.concat(currentData, newData));
      })
      .take(1)
      .subscribe();
  }

}


interface Material{
  id: number,
  name: string,
  article_id: string,
  tags: object,
  state: string,
  gallery_image: string
}
```

I did make sure that I imported everything properly and everything **seems** to work except I'm getting this `Property 'do' does not exist on type 'void'.` in the component class.

The main idea of what I want to do is retrieving the data from firebase one batch at a time and load more on scroll event, to achieve this so called "Infinite Scroll" to reduce server load.

Comment: What version of RxJS would be used in your project?

Comment: It's 5.5.6 @BradenVanWagenen

Comment: Have you tried using `pipe` and `tap` instead of `do`?

Comment: Yep, `getData` doesn't return anything. It's not clear why you think you could call `.do` on that nothing.

Comment: I didn't think to look into the service itself. That sounds right.

Comment: I was hoping it would return but clearly it doesn't. And I'm trying to make it return the data from firebase. This is the problem. @jonrsharpe

Comment: Given that you don't `return` and you're `subscribe`-ing to the observable in that method, I'd say you should revisit that. Don't hope it returns something, actually write code that does that!

Comment: What type should the `db.list` function return?

Comment: I have list of objects in Firebase, so I want it to return them in json @BradenVanWagenen

Comment: I think I would've not asked this question on here if I knew how to write code that does that. If you know, then kindly write a solution otherwise no need to tell me I should write code that works. @jonrsharpe

Comment: What? Your commented-out attempts *do* return something, so evidently you do know how to do that. The error message tells you exactly what the problem is, perhaps the ones you got for those attempts did too?

Comment: The first commented attempt gives "argument of type 'query' is not assignable to parameter of type 'QueryFn'. But that also removes the error with `.do`. So still error on either side. @jonrsharpe

Answer (score 0):

Firebase APIs are asynchronous, which means they return immediately when invoked, and the data you're looking for becomes available later in a callback.  In the code you showed, your callback is trying to `return materialData` from within a closure, which is not possible.  Put some log statements in your code, and you'll see that the `getData` function actually returns (undefined) before the callback is invoked.

Bottom line is that you can't make an asynchronous call synchronous, and you would never want to, because that would block your code and make your app janky.  You'll need to deal with Firebase APIs asynchronously as they were intended.

To learn more about why the Firebase APIs are asynchronous and what to expect from them, [read this blog](https://medium.com/google-developers/why-are-the-firebase-apis-asynchronous-e037a6654a93).

Comment: I do understand the asynchronous & synchronous concepts. Its just not clear to me how to go on about it in my case, returning data from firebase asynchronously with the parameters and methods I need to use to achieve the Infinite Scroll. Attempted many times but failed.

Comment: Then I would suggest asking another question that focuses on the problem of infinite scrolling, rather than the issue of why you apparently can't call a method on a void/undefined thing (and that you're trying to return a value in the wrong scope).

Comment: The issue here isn't solely on how to achieve Infinite Scroll but how to make a proper --asynchronous-- call to firebase and retrieve data so that I can properly use the returned data in my component, the rest is done already. For sure if I was going to ask another question people would just tell me I can't code this and that and not give a clear solution instead.

Comment: Just have your method accept a callback that you invoke from the Firestore callback, or return a promise that the caller can use to find out when the database is available.  You're just wrapping an API, so make your function look like that API.

Comment: Just to be clear here: your *actual* question is this: "How do I make a function return data from an asynchronous function?"  If you google something along those lines, including the term "javascript", you'll find this as the top hit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call